# Is there an Azure devops rest API to manage the process level security

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

My Application, needs to grant permission for users to add new work item type or to edit existing work item type of an existing process.

Is there an Azure devops rest API to manage the process level security ?

I could not find any such API in the documentation.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: By "existing process" above, i meant, any existing inherited process.

Comment: Not get your latest information, is the workaround helpful for you? Or if you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Comment: Hugh Lin, Thanks a lot for your immediate response.  I need one more help. I am not sure on how/from where to get the values for descriptor field. Can you please help me on that. I wanted to grant permission for a group created on Azure active directory. I just have the name of the group. Please guide me on how to get the descriptor using the group name.

Comment: For this, this [ticket](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/627087/how-to-lookup-descriptors-for-use-within-the-azure.html) could help you. For detailed information about the rest api I use, please refer to the official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/security/access%20control%20entries/set%20access%20control%20entries?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#identitydescriptor).

Comment: Hugh Lin, Thanks for your help. I wanted to know on how to get the IdentityDescriptor. Finally i got to know that the decoded form of GroupDescriptor can serve as IdentityDescriptor here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> needs to grant permission for users to add new work item type or to
> edit existing work item type of an existing process

To customize a process, you need to grant `Edit process` permissions to a user account for the specific process.

I grabbed the following api from the network of the browser to set the `Edit process` permission to `Allow`.

```
POST  https://dev.azure.com/{org}/_apis/AccessControlEntries/2dab47f9-bd70-49ed-9bd5-8eb051e59c02?api-version=5.1-preview
```

Sample request body:

```
{
    "token": "$PROCESS:adcc42ab-9882-485e-a3ed-7678f01f66bc:93xxxxe3-1510-4ae5-9019-f770318a3444:",
    "merge": true,
    "accessControlEntries": [{
        "descriptor": "Microsoft.IdentityModel.Claims.ClaimsIdentity;00037FFE1EBE3CEA@Live.com",
        "allow": 1,
        "deny": 0,
        "extendedInfo": {
            "effectiveAllow": 1,
            "effectiveDeny": 0,
            "inheritedAllow": 1,
            "inheritedDeny": 0
        }
    }]
}
```

[image]

Test in Postman:

[image]

**Update**:

The decoded form of GroupDescriptor can serve as IdentityDescriptor here.